# Android custom url scheme - empty host

Tags: android, android-manifest, url-scheme

I want to create a custom url scheme and the url should look like:

zf-moments://p1234567890

I define it in manifest as:

```
<data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="zf-moments" />
```

The problem is my activity is started on every link click. I guess the problem is with host but I want the host to be any. Probably the host is checked 1st, then the scheme. How to define the manifest so that only above links clicks open my app?

Thanks

Comment: "The problem is my activity is started on every link click" -- it should only work for links of the form `zf-moments://...` (for some `...`). Are you saying that this is responding for stuff like `http://` URLs too? Do you get the same behavior if you remove the `-`?

Comment: Yes. It is responding to links like "http://" most probably because the host is "*". Any ideas?

Comment: And if I remove "-" and set the scheme to "zfmoments" the problem still exists.

Comment: If you drop the `android:host` attribute, does that change matters? The scheme is supposed to be always enforced (see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#DataTest)

Comment: If I don't specify host, I have other problem. When I click zf-moments://p12313213 link in chrome, Chrome reports an error ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

Comment: Look like the problem is somewhere else. I had additional schemes for my activity and they seemed to be problem. If I removed all other http(s) schemes, my custom scheme works as expected.

Comment: It was: <data
                    android:host="*.zenfolio.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*.zenfolio.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*.zenfolio.us"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <data
                    android:host="*.zenfolio.us"
                    android:scheme="https" />
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:scheme="zf-moments" />

Comment: Now it is <data
                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:scheme="zf-moments" />